# Save to excel with Python and Pandas every X loops

Tags: python, web-crawler

I am learning to scrape and while I was testing one or two pages at a time, I was able to save the scraped data to excel with pandas at the end of all the loops.  However, now that I am testing with 50 pages, there is a risk an error will be found before the final save, so I would like to periodically save every 10 loops, however I'm not sure what additional code I would need to inject into my project.

I have tried moving the "save" code to the end of each loops, but it appears to create too many files (and each file seems to have the cumulative data whereas I would like just the incremental changes - or those changes that happened since the last save -  to be saved).  Code as follows:

This is where the loops starts"

```
#loop through the dictionaries to populate url
for province, cityValues in provinceDictionary.items():
    for city, code in cityValues.items():
        for category, categoryValues in businessCategoryDictionary.items():
            for catname, catcode in categoryValues.items():
                
                for page in pageNumbers:
                    url = (baseURL.format(province, city, catname, code, catcode))
                    
                    #Get the contents of the page we're looking at by requesting the URL
                    results = requests.get((url) + str(page) + ".html", headers=headers)

                    print('now processing page ' + str(results.url))

                    #parse html content
                    soup = BeautifulSoup(results.text, "html.parser")
                    
                    #Grab the container that holds the company info
                    companies_div = soup.find_all('div', {'id': re.compile('result-id-.*')})

                    #control the speed of the loop
                    sleep(randint(2, 10))

                    for x in companies_div:
                        name = x.h2.a.text
                        print(name)
                        names.append(name)

                        
#save to excel after all loops completed
#eliminates truncation in pd dataframe
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None)

#ininitalize pd dataframe
companies = pd.DataFrame({
    'Name': names,
    'Address': addresses,
    'Province': provinces,
    'Postal Code': postalCodes,
    'Category': categories,
    'URLs': urls
    })


companies.to_excel('test_' + str(int(time.time())) + '.xlsx', index=False)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm unclear where you're stuck.  First, you've dumped 150 lines of code on us for what seems to be a question of perhaps 5 lines.  You have your iteration loop, you have what appears to be a loop counter, and you have your block of code to save your progress.  As best I can tell, your question is a long-winded "how do I count to 10?" ... which is highly unlikely to be the case, given the coding abilities you show already.  Can you please clarify your specific need?

Comment: The answer was surprisingly simple.  Updated for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by creating a variable called loopcount, which tracks how many loops have been iterated through.  Once the loops hits desired number (10 in this case), it executes the save procedure and then resets the counter to 1.

```
loopCount = 1

#loop through the dictionaries to populate url
for province, cityValues in provinceDictionary.items():
    for city, code in cityValues.items():
        for category, categoryValues in businessCategoryDictionary.items():
            for catname, catcode in categoryValues.items():
                
                for page in pageNumbers:
                    url = (baseURL.format(province, city, catname, code, catcode))
                    
                    #Get the contents of the page we're looking at by requesting the URL
                    results = requests.get((url) + str(page) + ".html", headers=headers)

                    print('now processing page ' + str(results.url))

                    #parse html content
                    soup = BeautifulSoup(results.text, "html.parser")
                    
                    #Grab the container that holds the company info
                    companies_div = soup.find_all('div', {'id': re.compile('result-id-.*')})

                    #control the speed of the loop
                    sleep(randint(2, 10))
                    
                    #increase the loop count each time
                    loopCount +=1
                    print('currently on loop' + str(loopCount))
                  
                    # every 10 loops, save
                    if loopCount == 10:
                        #eliminates truncation in pd dataframe
                        pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
                        pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
                        pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None)

                        #ininitalize pd dataframe
                        companies = pd.DataFrame({
                            'Name': names
                            })


                        companies.to_csv('results_' + str(int(time.time())) + '.csv', index=False)
                        #reset loop count to 1 after saving 
                        loopCount = 1
                        print('currently on loop' + str(loopCount))
```